# Forward one special http URL to https URL with port via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https, url-rewriting

For our website we need a redirection of the following Login URL

http://lit.example.com/index.php?action=initLogon

to

https://lit.example.com:60558/index.php?action=initLogon

I didn't find any solution for this in the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=initLogon
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ https://lit.example.com:60558/index.php [R,L]
```

This checks if it is a plain HTTP request and looks, if the query string is indeed `action=initLogon`. If it is, it then redirects the client to the new HTTPS URL.